# Would it be possible for us to create an object that is accessible for all operators in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, stream-processing

I am building a class that helps monitor the numerical performance of multiple operators. My current idea of doing it is to create a method like `update()`, and call this method every time there is a need for the operators to update something. However, this means I need to create an object that is visible to every single operator that I wish to monitor. Would this be possible? Or would there be any better solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you know that all operators are running in a single JVM (you have one Task Manager) then you can create a singleton that all operators can use to log activity.

If it's a Flink cluster with multiple TMs, then each is running in their own JVM, so you'd have to use some distributed system to record this activity.

The cheesy solution would be to use logging, and then post-process the logs to extract the information you need.

Or you might be able to use Flink's built-in metrics to collect the information you need.